# Wordpress и визуальный редактор

Tags: php, html, wordpress, html5

Не могу найти информацию как натягивать шаблон на `wp`, чтобы можно было редактировать в визуальном редакторе. Ссылки на информацию как это делать приветствуются.

Comment: Какой "визуальный редактор"? И вообще - ты ВП видел?  Забей на "натягивания", учи ВП. А то ты сейчас даже терминологию не знаешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тебе бутстрап тема для wp [github](https://github.com/saxap/clean-wp-template).
Сверстай шапку и подвал [(ссылка где боле менее понятно как интегрировать их)](https://youtu.be/7akPICFR-AI). Дальше установи visual composer в wp и верстай страницы на нём в админки и будет тебе счастья)